# How to prevent classes from inheriting static variables?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm making a bootleg agar.io. Every time a Blob is created (the parent class for all circular entities in the game including players and food), a reference will be stored in a static array for the Blob class. I want to do the same exact thing (create a static array of all instances of a class) for the Food class which extends the Blob class.

I've tried this: in the constructor for all three classes, the object is pushed to the `.all` static array so all instances can be accessed by `Blob.all` or `Food.all`. To initialize the static variable before pushing `this`, I realized I need to set `.all` to an empty array if equal to null.

```
const Blob = class extends Point { 
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0, radius = 5, color = `rgb(0, 0, 0)`) {
        super(x, y)
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
        this.deleted = false
        Blob.all = Blob.all || []
        Blob.all.push(this)
    }

    static draw(ctx) {
        Blob.all.forEach(blob => blob.draw(ctx))
    }

    // ...

    delete() {
        this.deleted = true
        Blob.all.filter(blob => blob !== this)
    }
}


const Food = class extends Blob { 
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
        super(x, y, 5, `rgb(255, 150, 120)`)
        Food.all = Food.all || []
        Food.all.push(this)
    }

    static draw(ctx) {
        Food.all.forEach(food => food.draw(ctx))
    }

    // ...

    delete() {
        super.delete()
        Food.all.filter(food => food !== this)
    }
}


const Player = class extends Blob { 
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0, color = `rgb(100, 100, 100)`) {
        super(x, y, 20, color)
        Player.all = Player.all || []
        Player.all.push(this)
    }

    static draw(ctx) {
        Player.all.forEach(player => player.draw(ctx))
    }

    // ...

    delete() {
        super.delete()
        Player.all.filter(player => player !== this)
    }
}


// ...


// oversimplification of how I'm initializing and looping my game
gameInit = _ => {
     // creates 100 new instances of Food
     for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) new Food(randX, randY)

     // creates 1 new instance of a player
     let player = new Player()
}

drawLoop = _ => {
     Food.draw(ctx)
     Player.draw(ctx)
}
```

After `gameInit()`, I EXPECT `Player.all` to be an array of 1 instance (1 Player object).
I also expect `Food.all` to be an array of 100 instances (100 Food objects).
I also expect `Blob.all` to be an array of 101 instances (100 Food objects, 1 Player object).

Turns out, `Player.all`, `Food.all`, `Blob.all` area all equal! They are all sharing the same static variable. Not only is it NOT what I want for them to all share the same variable, but there are 202 objects in that array because when `Food` is created, it gets pushed to the static variable twice.

How do I get the expected results?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `Food.all` will look up the inherited array stored under `Blob.all`, so this:

```
  Food.all = Food.all || [];
```

basically does

```
 Food.all = Blob.all /*|| []*/;
```

To store new arrays under each class, you should manually instantiate them outside of the class declarations:

```
 class Food extends Blob { /*...*/ }
 Food.all = [];
```

> when Food is created, it gets pushed to the static variable twice.

Sure, because every Food is a Blob too, therefore it gets pushed to Blob.all *and* to Food.all.

---

Note: By creating these arrays you prevent all Blob objects from getting garbage collected as you keep a reference to them. You have to manually remove them from the array to make them viable for garbagge collection (as you do with your `.delete` methods).

Answer (score 1):

You could overload the static property for each class

```
const Player = class extends Blob { 
    static all = [];

    // rest of the implementation
}
```

That way the property would be actually different for every class.

Comment: Wasn't it implemented in the ES6 version of JS ? How else could he access Food.all if it isn't a static property already ?

Comment: `class Player { /*...*/ }` is more or less equal to `function Player() { /*...*/ }` (there are some special things going on under the hood, I'm simplifying here) and functions are just objects, and you can add properties to objects. Thats what the OP does. The `static all = []` creates that property too, but it uses a new syntax, that is currently stage 3 of the proposal, so its probably es2019

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but unless I'm misunderstanding something it seems available already https://jsfiddle.net/kgwt0d5h/

Comment: Yes, they shipped with chrome 72 https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6001727933251584

Answer (score 0):

you can't prevent it, but you can work around it.

First you can explicitely initialize the Array for each class, as Jonas Wilms showed:

```
const Blob = class extends Point { 
...
}
Blob.all = [];

const Food = class extends Blob { 
...
}
// at this point, Food has inherited the Array `all`, but you can overwrite it with an own one
Food.all = [];
```

and so on. And you can get rid of these checks `Blob.all = Blob.all || []` as you have explicitely initialized each Array.

---

V2: you can check wether the Array `all` belongs to the current class

```
if(!hasOwnProperty.call(Blob, "all")) Blob.all = [];
```

and the same for the other classes. Maybe putting this logic in a function.

---

V3: Why don't you use seperate Varialbles for the Arrays?

```
const allBlobs = [];
const Blob = class extends Point { 
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0, radius = 5, color = `rgb(0, 0, 0)`) {
        ...
        allBlobs.push(this)
    }

    static draw(ctx) {
        allBlobs.forEach(blob => blob.draw(ctx))
    }

    delete() {
        ...
        allBlobs.filter(blob => blob !== this)
    }
};

const allFoods = [];
const Food = class extends Blob { 
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
        super(x, y, 5, `rgb(255, 150, 120)`)
        allFoods.push(this)
    }
    ...
}
```

If you're using any kind of Modules, these Variables are also encapsulated insides these Modules and not public.

Comment: There are a few more ways to work around this problem, like IIFEs and Symbols, but these "solutions" are getting imo. too fancy to include them in the Answer.